# How to truncate words that are too long with CSS3?

Tags: css, html, text, truncate

Is there the possibility to cut off a word that runs out of a containing box (like a div or paragraph) with CSS3? The `white-space: nowrap;` property does not work for me because my text is written in multiple lines and `white-space: nowrap;` makes a one-liner out of my text.

Here is a screenshot of my problem:
[image]

Comment: You can use `overflow`: [CSS Manual Overflow](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow)

Comment: I already use overflow: hidden which cuts the text at the orange border. But the word "ApxStuaaaa..." is still too long so I want to recognize that and replace this word with "..."

Comment: Without any server-side code? CSS only?

Comment: JavaScript would also be fine.

Answer (score 1):

JS:

```
max_length = 20;
my_full_text = "My long long text aksjdhfka jshdf kjahds fasdf";
if(my_full_text.length >= max_length){
  trimmed_text = my_full_text.substring(0, max_length);
}else{
  trimmed_text = my_full_text;
}

alert(trimmed_text)
```

Where `20` is the max length you want the text to be.

Comment: Uh. Thank you very much! I also found this plugin: http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/ and a very nice tutorial: http://mikemclin.net/text-overflow-ellipsis/